# Display Show More / Show Less option if text if more then 20 length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatable

I try to add option in my Debatable column Description if text length is more then 20 character long display `Show more` option and collapse this column.
I try couple of option and one which work for me is something like this

```
function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Manager/Ticket/GetAll"
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "description",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return type === 'display' && data.length > 20 ?
                    '<span title="' + data + '">' + data.substr(0, 17) + '...</span>' :
                    data;
            }
        }],
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "description",
                "width": "10%",
                //"render": function (data) {
                //    return '<a href="#" id="showmore">Prikazi vise</a>'
                //}
            },
            { "data": "shortDescription", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "ticketType.name", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "status", "width": "10%" },
            {
                "data": "applicationUser.name",
                "width": "10%",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a id="' + data + '" class="text-info user-details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDetails" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                            <div class="text-center">   
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Details/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                   <i class="fas fa-info-circle">Detalji/Chat</i>
                                </a>   
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Upsert/${data}" class="btn btn-primary text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit">Uredi</i>
                                </a>                           
                            </div>
                           `;
                }, "width": "15%"
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

After I add `columnsDef`

```
"columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "description",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return type === 'display' && data.length > 20 ?
                    '<span title="' + data + '">' + data.substr(0, 17) + '...</span>' :
                    data;
            }
        }],
```

This option works but only when User hover column it display text.  I add `...` and I want to create that this tree dots needs to be as `<a>` and should be clickable and when user click it needs to Show More and Show Less option.
I check couple of post here starting from this

[REFERENCE 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128483/show-more-show-less-with-jquery)

The problem here is that I am noob in jQuery and JavaScript and I have no idea how to implement this side.

This is how it look like right now

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found some solutions but doesn't work at all. I change my `columnDef`

```
"columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 0,
        "data": "description",
        "render": function (data, type) {
            return type === 'display' && data.length > 20 ?
                '<span id="outer" data-shrink="' + data.substr(0, 17) + '"  title="' + data + '"></span><span id="show">...</span>' :
                data;
        }
    }],
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tblData").hide();
    $(".showmore").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".tblData").is(':visible') ? 'Vise' : 'Manje';
        $(".showmore").text(txt);
        $(this).next('.tblData').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

I successfully add `...` to be clickable, but when I click text is not showing.

**UPDATE**

```
"columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "description",
            "render": function (data, type) {
                return type === 'display' && data.length > 20 ?
                    '<span id="outer" title="' + data + '">' + data.substr(0, 17) + '</span><span id="show">...</span>' :
                    data;
            }
        }],



$('#show').click(function () {
    var text = $('#outer').attr('title');
    $(this).text(text);
    $('#show').after('<a id="less" onclick="someFunction()" href="#"> Show less</a>');
    $('#outer').text('');
});


function someFunction() {
    console.log('test');
    $('#less').remove();
    var txt = $('#outer').attr('data-shrink');
    $('#show').text('');
    $('#outer').text(txt);
    $('#show').text('...');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var len = $('#outer').text();
if(len.length > 20) {
   var txt = $('#outer').attr('data-shrink');
   console.log(txt);
   $('#outer').text(txt);
   $('#show').text('...');
}

$('#show').click(function() {
  var text = $('#outer').attr('title');
  console.log('text', text.length);
  $(this).text(text);
  $('#show').after('<a id="less" onclick="someFunction()" href="#"> Show less</a>');
  $('#outer').text('');
});


function someFunction() {
  console.log('test');
  $('#less').remove();
  var txt = $('#outer').attr('data-shrink');
  $('#show').text('');
  $('#outer').text(txt);
  $('#show').text('...');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="outer" data-shrink="Das ist ein" title="Das ist ein ganzer Text langer Text">Das ist ein sehr langer Text</span><span id="show"></span>
```

Just replace the html with your variables.

Comment: You should inspect your tabledata in the Developer Tools.

Comment: I inspect alredy but I have some problem which I don't know where it is

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Can you please update answer recording to my question. If you need some aditional information please let me know. I would be very thankfull

Comment: This answer is ok for me, but I need also `show less` option.

Comment: You have a button for show less or on click on the whole text? Yes, but if the whole text ist displayed. So should it shrink if you click on the whole text and 17 characters and the dots are displayed again?

Comment: No button, I have `...` or it should be also `<a> tag`

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/x6w37dqf/1/

Comment: updated my answer. Just run the code above. Should work now.

Comment: Doesn't work. I update my question. Check UPDATE section

Comment: Check it again. You don't have data-shrink="' + data.substr(0, 17) + '" added. Just see my example.

Comment: `"columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 0,
            "data": "description",
            "render": function (data, type) {
                return type === 'display' && data.length > 20 ?
                    //'<span id="outer"  title="' + data + '">' + data.substr(0, 17) + '</span><span id="show">...</span>' :
                    '<span id="outer" data-shrink="Das ist ein" title="Das ist ein ganzer Text">Das ist ein</span><span id="show">...</span>':
                    data;
            }
        }],`

Comment: If you click on ... and after that you continue clicking on that span, it will show multiple `Show less` buttons. Just change little bit logic on #show click handler.
`$('#show').click(function() {
  var text = $('#outer').attr('title');
  $(this).text('');
  $('#outer').text(text);
  $('#show').after('<a id="less" onclick="someFunction()" href="#"> Show less</a>');
});`

Comment: @J.Kovacevic The problem here is that after I use the code which @Bernhard Beatus it display only `...`. But it should display `data` and if text is longer then 20 character it shoudl display first 17 character and `...` which should be `clickable` and display rest of text

Comment: just test it again. Did some changes. Now it should work.

Comment: What should I pass to `columnDef` 
`<span id="outer" data-shrink="Das ist ein" title="Das ist ein ganzer Text langer Text">Das ist ein ist langer ganz langer text</span><span id="show">...</span>`

Comment: This is  what I get as output 
https://imgur.com/xEgCUT0

Comment: Made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/ga9ucfro/4/

Comment: Doesnt work at all. I have no idea but fiddler DEMO also doesnt work !

Comment: <span id="outer" data-shrink="' + data.substr(0,17) + '" title="' + data +'">' + data.substr(0,17) + '</span><span id="show"></span>

I`m out. Sorry

The Fiddle demo works great. You just have to change the the title attribute to a text is greater or less than 20 sign.

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussions so go to this page. It's a forum for datatables.

Comment: Hi I made a new fiddle. Not pefect but you can try.
https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/u47en98v/100/
Show less is not working. Maybe you can improve the code

Comment: @BernhardBeatus Hi thank you for you help ! I will test it :)

Comment: Ok I got it. Test it again. Maybe you have to adjust the text length to 20 signs. This was just for testing. Check it out!
https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/u47en98v/139/
Please check it as answered if my code fits you.

Comment: I replaced the word less with row.name. So if the word or sentence is shorter the name will be displayed. See https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/u47en98v/141/

Comment: I get error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`