# How to make a "Show more/ Show less" button for a div component? (Not for a paragraph)

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am creating a *product landing web page* which sells musical instruments...
Now, I want my page to show a button to show more. But in my case, the page doesn't have only text. I want to add a whole div tag to show more.
I read various articles but they work only for text.

```css
#product-info {
  margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, 
    rgba(123,67,151,1) 0%, 
    rgba(220,36,48,1) 100%);
    align-items: center;
    height: 220rem;
    padding-top: 100px;

  }
  
/* FOR GUITAR */
#guitarbox {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#guitarbox:hover {
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

#guitarcontent {
  margin: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#guitarbox img {
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
/* GUITAR END */
  
/* FOR KEYBOARD */
#keyboardbox {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#keyboardcontent {
  margin: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#keyboardbox:hover {
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

#keyboardbox img {
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
/* KEYBOARD END */

/* FOR VIOLIN */
#violinbox {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#violinbox:hover {
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

#violincontent {
  margin: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#violinbox img {
  margin-right: 0;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
/* VIOLIN END */
  
/* FOR CELLO */
#cellobox {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#cellobox:hover {
  background-color: #bebebe;
}

#cellocontent {
  margin: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#cellobox img {
  border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
/* CELLO END */
```

```html
<section id="product-info" class="product-info">
    <b>Here are the instruments that our brand serves: </b>
    <div class="guitar">
        <div id="guitarbox">
            <div id="guitarcontent">
                <h1>Guitar</h1><hr>
                <p>
                    An electric guitar is a guitar that requires 
                    external amplification in order to be heard at 
                    typical performance volumes, unlike a standard 
                    acoustic guitar. It uses one or more pickups to 
                    convert the vibration of its strings into 
                    electrical signals, which ultimately are 
                    reproduced as sound by loudspeakers.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="guitarimg">
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_guitar" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/images/electric-guitar.jpg" width="500px">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="keyboard">
        <div id="keyboardbox">
            <div id="keyboardcontent">
                <h1>Keyboard</h1><hr>
                <p>
                    A musical keyboard is the set of adjacent depressible 
                    levers or keys on a musical instrument. 
                    Keyboards typically contain keys for playing the 
                    twelve notes of the Western musical scale, with a 
                    combination of larger, longer keys and smaller, 
                    shorter keys that repeats at the interval of an octave.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="keyboardimg">
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_keyboard" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/images/keyboard2.png" width="500px">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="violin">
        <div id="violinbox">
            <div id="violincontent">
                <h1>Violin</h1><hr>
                <p>
                    The violin, sometimes known as a fiddle, is a 
                    wooden chordophone (string instrument) in the 
                    violin family. Most violins have a hollow wooden 
                    body. It is the smallest and thus highest-pitched 
                    instrument (soprano) in the family in regular use.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="violinimg">
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/images/violin.jpg" width="500px">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cello">
        <div id="cellobox">
            <div id="cellocontent">
                <h1>Cello</h1><hr>
                <p>
                    The cello (/ˈtʃɛloʊ/ CHEL-oh; plural celli or 
                    cellos) or violoncello (/ˌvaɪələnˈtʃɛloʊ/ VY-ə-lən-CHEL-oh; 
                    Italian pronunciation: [vjolonˈtʃɛllo]) is a 
                    bowed (sometimes plucked and occasionally hit) 
                    string instrument of the violin family.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="celloimg">
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_keyboard" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/images/cello2.jpeg" width="500px">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here, I want the div **below the keyboard** to be in show more...

I tried referring to various sites but couldn't find a solution for this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alok Marathe. Please check for below code for your issue. There is lot of code on stack-overflow that provides you idea how to do show more functionality.

they will give you example with working you need to just implement on that.

Here is Stack-overflow Link and your code is below.

[stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128483/show-more-show-less-with-jquery)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    //this will execute on page load(to be more specific when document ready event occurs)
    if ($('.product-info-box').length > 2) {
        $('.product-info-box:gt(1)').hide();
        $('.showmore').show();
    }

    $('.showmore button').on('click', function () {
        //toggle elements with class that their index is bigger than 2
        $('.product-info-box:gt(1)').toggle();
        //change text of show more element just for demonstration purposes to this demo
        $(this).text() === 'Show less' ? $(this).text('Show more') : $(this).text('Show less');
    });

});
```

```css
/* Just For Example No Need */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* Your CSS */
#product-info {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: "Cinzel", serif;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(123, 67, 151, 1) 0%, rgba(220, 36, 48, 1) 100%);
    align-items: center;
    height: initial;
    padding-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

/* FOR GUITAR */
#guitarbox {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
    transition: 1s;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#guitarbox:hover {
    background-color: #bebebe;
}

#guitarcontent {
    margin: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#guitarbox img {
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

/* GUITAR END */

/* FOR KEYBOARD */
#keyboardbox {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
    transition: 1s;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#keyboardcontent {
    margin: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#keyboardbox:hover {
    background-color: #bebebe;
}

#keyboardbox img {
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

/* KEYBOARD END */

/* FOR VIOLIN */
#violinbox {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
    transition: 1s;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#violinbox:hover {
    background-color: #bebebe;
}

#violincontent {
    margin: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#violinbox img {
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

/* VIOLIN END */

/* FOR CELLO */
#cellobox {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(237, 244, 199);
    transition: 1s;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#cellobox:hover {
    background-color: #bebebe;
}

#cellocontent {
    margin: 30px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#cellobox img {
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

/* CELLO END */


/* Custom CSS */

/* Fixed div height */
.product_info_scroll {
    
}

/*  Not Necessary */
.showmore {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="product-info" class="product-info">
        <b>Here are the instruments that our brand serves: </b>
        <!-- This div for making fixed height of show content -->
        <div class="product_info_scroll">
            
            <div class="guitar product-info-box">
                <div id="guitarbox">
                    <div id="guitarcontent">
                        <h1>Guitar</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <p>
                            An electric guitar is a guitar that requires
                            external amplification in order to be heard at
                            typical performance volumes, unlike a standard
                            acoustic guitar. It uses one or more pickups to
                            convert the vibration of its strings into
                            electrical signals, which ultimately are
                            reproduced as sound by loudspeakers.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="guitarimg">
                        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_guitar" target="_blank">
                            <img src="/images/electric-guitar.jpg" width="500px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="keyboard product-info-box">
                <div id="keyboardbox">
                    <div id="keyboardcontent">
                        <h1>Keyboard</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <p>
                            A musical keyboard is the set of adjacent depressible
                            levers or keys on a musical instrument.
                            Keyboards typically contain keys for playing the
                            twelve notes of the Western musical scale, with a
                            combination of larger, longer keys and smaller,
                            shorter keys that repeats at the interval of an octave.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="keyboardimg">
                        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_keyboard" target="_blank">
                            <img src="/images/keyboard2.png" width="500px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="violin product-info-box">
                <div id="violinbox">
                    <div id="violincontent">
                        <h1>Violin</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <p>
                            The violin, sometimes known as a fiddle, is a
                            wooden chordophone (string instrument) in the
                            violin family. Most violins have a hollow wooden
                            body. It is the smallest and thus highest-pitched
                            instrument (soprano) in the family in regular use.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="violinimg">
                        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violin" target="_blank">
                            <img src="/images/violin.jpg" width="500px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cello product-info-box">
                <div id="cellobox">
                    <div id="cellocontent">
                        <h1>Cello</h1>
                        <hr>
                        <p>
                            The cello (/ˈtʃɛloʊ/ CHEL-oh; plural celli or
                            cellos) or violoncello (/ˌvaɪələnˈtʃɛloʊ/ VY-ə-lən-CHEL-oh;
                            Italian pronunciation: [vjolonˈtʃɛllo]) is a
                            bowed (sometimes plucked and occasionally hit)
                            string instrument of the violin family.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="celloimg">
                        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_keyboard" target="_blank">
                            <img src="/images/cello2.jpeg" width="500px">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="showmore">
            <button type="button">Show More</button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Smit Dudhat. That helped :). Can you please also tell me how to smoothen the display? Its displaying too fast when I click Show more. Thanks!

Comment: @AlokMarathe you can look into [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/). It gives you lots of options to animate your blocks.